# Как запаролить страничку с помощью php?

Tags: php

Я хотел сделать так: заходишь на `Page` (ее необходимо запаролить), тебя переадресовывает на страничку с формой логин и пароль; если вводишь верно, то переходишь на страничку `Page`. Но тут проблема, после ввода верного пароля переходишь на страничку `Page` и она опять кидает тебя на ввод пароля. Замкнутый круг. Есть у кого-нибудь что-то подобное, более рабочее? Скиньте.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю так совсем просто:

```
<?php
if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])) {
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="My Realm"');
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
    echo 'Текст, отправляемый в том случае,
    если пользователь нажал кнопку Cancel';
    exit;
} else {
    echo "<p>Hello {$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']}.</p>";
    echo "<p>Вы ввели пароль {$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']}.</p>";
}
?>
```

Взято [тут](http://php.net/manual/ru/features.http-auth.php)

Answer (score 4):

Суть в том, что сервер должен запомнить, что ты прошел авторизацию и аутентификацию. Эти сведения тебе помогут сохранить данные об успешной авторизации:

[Сессии](http://phpfaq.ru/sessions)

[Куки](http://php.su/phphttp/?cookies)

Answer (score 3):

На [youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=foptrvfCqdk) есть хороший туториал, за одно и [исходник](http://www.phpvault.net/) можно скачать, называется **Login System**!

Answer (score 2):

А не легче все сделать через htaccess ???

Допустим у вас есть сайт www.site.ru, а по адресу www.site.ru/webadmin/ у вас находится система администрирования сайта, доступ к которой должен быть ограничен паролем. Для этого вам необходимо создать в директории /webadmin/ два файла: .htaccess и .htpasswd.

Содержимое файла .htaccess:

> AuthType basic
>
> AuthName 'Authorization...'
>
> AuthUserFile '/.../www/webadmin/.htpasswd'
>
> Require valid-user
>
> DirectoryIndex admin.php

Для вас важны третья и пятая строчки, остальные менять не нужно. В третьей строке между одинарными кавычками указан путь к файлу .htpasswd от корневой директории сервера. Как правило эта информация (путь от корня сервера) предоставляется хостером среди прочей информации об арендуемой фтп-площадке. В пятой строке указан файл, который будет загружаться по умолчанию (в случае если вы не указали конкретный файл в адресной строке).

В файле .htpasswd хранятся логин и пароль к папке. Выглядит содержимое этого файла примерно следующим образом:

login:$apr1$fH4.....$hMovWyy.EMp5FAW4TEUDH/

- логин и через двоеточие пароль, зашифрованный по системе MD5.

Взято отсюда [тык](http://www.seo-amateur.ru/parol.php)

Answer (score 1):

Это самый простенький вариант, попробуй его:

```
<?php

// Инициализация переменных  
    $user_login = !empty($_POST['user_login'])?$_POST['user_login']:NULL;  
    $user_password = !empty($_POST['user_password'])?$_POST['user_password']:NULL;

// Устанавливаем логин - пароль  
    $login = 'Иванов';  
    $password = 'Ракета';

// Проверка  
    if($login === $user_login && $password === $user_password)  
        echo 'Проходи!';  
    else  
        echo 'Стой, стрелять буду!';  
?>  
<form action="" method="post">  
Логин <input name="user_login" type="text"><br>  
Пароль <input name="user_password" type="password"><br>  
<input name="ok" type="submit" value="Тук-тук">  
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Давай я еще проще предложу

```
<?
function input() {
    //принимаем по посту ник и пароль
    $userlogin = $_POST['userlogin'];
    $userpassword = $_POST['userpassword'];

    //проверяем сходятся введенные данные с имеющимися
    if($userlogin != 'login' && $userpassword != 'pass') {
    echo "Катись отсюда"; 
    } else {
    echo "добро пожаловать";
    }
}
?>
#форма
<form action="input()" method="post">  
Логин: <input name="userlogin" type="text"><br>  
Пароль: <input name="userpassword" type="password"><br>
<input name="send" type="submit" value="Отправить">  
</form>
```

Comment: подправь код

> Пароль: <input name="userpassword" type="password"><br>

Comment: >action="input()"

Давно веб-разработкой занимаетесь?

Comment: 3 года занимался, щас занимаюсь разработкой игр. Уже не помню когда последний раз писал код на php

Answer (score 1):

Лучше так:

```
//Страничка login.php
<?php
session_start();
$password = "thispass";
if (!empty($_POST['password']))
$trim_password = trim($_POST['password']);
{
if ($_trim_password != $password)
die ("Неверный пароль!");
else
{
$_SESSION['auth'] = "success";
header('Location: private.php');
}
}

//Страничка private.php
    <?php
session_start();
    if (empty($_SESSION['auth']))
    header('Location:login.php');
    else
    echo "Hello!";
    ?>
```

Уж думаю форму напишете сами. Не всё же за вас делать.